# Help with calculating a complicated expectation

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I'm trying to use *Mathematica* to help me simplify an expression involving expectations of products of powers for correlated, zero-mean, unit-variance normal variates. Specifically, for $(Z_1,Z_2,Z_3,Z_4)\sim N(0,\Sigma)$ where $\Sigma=(\rho_{ij})$ is the correlation matrix, I'd like to express $\mathbb{E}[(Z_1+Z_2+Z_3+Z_4)^4]$ in terms of the $\rho_{ij}$'s.

The results for the expectations of products of the $Z$'s up to 4th degree are known, for instance $\mathbb{E}(Z_j^4)=3$, $\mathbb{E}(Z_j^2Z_k^2)=1+2\rho_{jk}^2$ and $\mathbb{E}(Z_j^2Z_kZ_l)=2\rho_{jk}\rho_{jl}+\rho_{kl}$, etc. My goal is to substitute these expressions into the expansion of $\mathbb{E}[(Z_1+Z_2+Z_3+Z_4)^4]$ and simplify.

Apparently this is a very tedious task by hand. Is it even possible to do this in *Mathematica*? I'm OK with having to write some code for this, since my ultimate aim is to generalize this to $\mathbb{E}[(Z_1+\cdots+Z_d)^4]$, where $d>4$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does `Expectation[(Z1 + Z2 + Z3 + Z4)^4, {Z1, Z2, Z3, Z4} \[Distributed] 
  MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   Table[p[i, j], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]]]` not do what you want?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize it does that automatically without having to substitute expressions...

Comment: Would you like me to post it as an answer? (Or you could answer yourself, if you like.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Patrick Stevens gave the following expression in a comment:

```
Expectation[
  (Z1 + Z2 + Z3 + Z4)^4, {Z1, Z2, Z3, Z4} \[Distributed] 
    MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0, 0}, 
  Table[p[i, j], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]]]
```

It solves my problem.